# PHP: if { } parse error

Tags: php, parsing

I'm using this to determine if a variable is set. I am not a beginner and normally, this works (it's not complicated either)...

```
if(isset($ok)) { 
    [stuff happening]
}
```

This is the return: 
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in firstlaunch.php on line 6

The thing is, that's that. My file is empty but for those few lines. I'm used to fixing those types of problems but I can't see why the error is coming since that's the only PHP on my page.

Ideas?

Thanks a lot!

++++++
Edit: the full script is:

```
<?php 
$ok = isset($_GET['flag']);

if(isset($ok)) { 

}
?>
```

Comment: Does your script really contain the line `[stuff happening]`? If so, then I'd expect errors (missing `;` causing the error) ; if not, show what's really in your script

Comment: According to that error, there are at least 6 lines, please provide them all.

Comment: <?php 
$ok = isset($_GET['flag']);

if(isset($ok)) { 

}
?>

That's all there is, I just started this page.

Comment: @DamienBourdonneau Nope, no syntax errors there. https://3v4l.org/Kup1R Try again.

Comment: @JonStirling I know, it's driving me nuts. my IDE and my XAMPP seem to see a problem somewhere though... https://postimg.org/image/6vuo5u9oh/

Comment: You might have some dodgy invisible characters I suppose. Check with a hex editor.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `CTRL+A` and then delete it and then rewrite it? - Not sure what the cause is but you might have a invisible char somewhere.

Comment: thanks all, your HEX editor suggestion solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks a lot for the HEX editor suggestion, it worked: I had this thing between my { }:

```
¬†
```

Wonder where that came from... But now my file executes!

Thanks!